# Making checkbox bigger in size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the checkbox bigger in size. The regular size is too small

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please try to add more information about what you have done.

Answer (score 5):

Try CSS 'transform'

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  -ms-transform: scale(2); 
  -moz-transform: scale(2); 
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); 
  -o-transform: scale(2); 
  transform: scale(2); }
```

But it will not work on IE8.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the images to change the style of checkboxes.

You can also use the following CSS which has been tested in Chrome. But this won't work in Firefox:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
}
```

For a demo visit: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

This is tough to achieve if you want to maintain cross-browser compatiblity.

You may want to consider an input replacement plugin such as this one.

http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/